# Updating Data Causes Recycler View (List Adapter) To Move The Data To The End

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I am using List Adapter to display a list of strings.

[image]

Whenever I update data on the recycler view it scrolls the data to the end of the list

[image]

Any idea what is causing this?

for reference below is the code for the adapter

```
class TestAdapter(private val taskListener: DetailTaskAdapterListener) : ListAdapter<Task, TestAdapter.TestViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallback) {

    inner class TestViewHolder(private val binding: DetailSubTaskItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(task: Task) {
            binding.checkbox.isChecked = task.isComplete
            binding.task.setText(task.task.trim())
        }

        fun setupListener() {
            binding.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                if (isChecked) {
                    binding.task.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
                } else {
                    binding.task.paintFlags = 0
                }
                getItem(absoluteAdapterPosition).copy(isComplete = isChecked)
            }

            binding.task.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
                if(!hasFocus){
                    if(binding.task.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                        taskListener.deleteTask(getItem(absoluteAdapterPosition).taskId)
                    }else{
                        taskListener.updateTask(getItem(absoluteAdapterPosition).taskId, binding.task.text.toString().trim())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TestViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return TestViewHolder(
            DetailSubTaskItemBinding.inflate(
                layoutInflater, parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TestViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val task = getItem(position)
        holder.setupListener()
        holder.bind(task)
    }

    companion object DiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Task>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem.task == newItem.task
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Task, newItem: Task): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

code below is the DAO, (note: both insert and update function causes recyclerview to push updated data to the last row)

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE todoId = :todoId")
fun getTodoDetails(todoId: String): Flow<TodoDetailsEntity>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertTask(task: TaskEntity): Long

@Query("UPDATE task SET task = :title WHERE taskId = :taskId")
suspend fun updateTaskTitle(taskId: String, title: String): Int
```

Below is the entity model

```
data class TodoDetailsEntity(
    @Embedded val todo: TodoEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "todoId",
        entityColumn = "todoRefId"
    )
    val tasks: List<TaskEntity>,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "todoId",
        entityColumn = "noteId"
    )
    val note: NoteEntity?,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "todoId",
        entityColumn = "todoRefId"
    )
    val attachments: List<AttachmentEntity>
)
```

submitList is called in Activity onCreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.saveTodoId(intent.extras?.getString("todoId")!!)
        todoId = intent.extras?.getString("todoId")
        binding = ActivityDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupToolbar()
        setupTestAdapter()
        collectLatestLifecycleFlow(viewModel.uiState) { uiState ->

            testAdapter.submitList(uiState.todoDetails?.tasks)
        }
    }
```

For reference, whenever I update the data to database, ROOM will automatically move the data to the last index

Before updating

[image]

After update
[image]

Comment: can you share the code where you call the `adapter.submitData()`?

Comment: the adapter doesn't deal with the order, it just displays the data on the order you supplied.

Comment: @AlécioCarvalho thanks for looking into it. I've added more information to the bottom of the post. regarding ```adapter.submitList()``` it is called on activity oncreate

Comment: I see, you may need to add the `ORDER BY` on the `SELECT` query:


`@Query("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE todoId = :todoId ORDER BY title ASC")`

or another column that makes more sense for your app.

Comment: Yeah I am implementing your suggestion regarding sorting by adding "position" into the entity. I am certain I've introduced bugs somewhere. I'll keep looking around again. Thanks for the help!